# Need a solution for redirecting or include in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a jsp index file wherein there is a simple login form and I check the values presented by the user at the controller and redirect them to the repectable jsp page which have other functionality.

Here's my **index file:**

```
<html>
</head> <body>  <b><span class="heading">LOGIN USER</span></b>  <div class="container">
        <form action="login.html" method="Post">
            <div class="form_style">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"/>
            <select name="dept">
                <option>IT</option>
                <option>Admin</option>
                <option>HR</option>
                <option>Marketing</option>
            </select>
            <input type="Submit" value="submit">

            </div>
        </form>
    </div> </body>

</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class LoginController {  
    @RequestMapping("/login")  
    public ModelAndView loginResult(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {
        InfoEmployee inf = new InfoEmployee();
        InfoManager inf2 = new InfoManager();
        String uname=req.getParameter("username");  
        //Putting the username in the session object


        String pwd=req.getParameter("pwd");  
        String dept = req.getParameter("dept");
        String name1 = inf.getName();
        String message1 = "Welcome "+name1;  
        String name2 = inf2.getName();
        String message2 = "Welcome "+name2;
        if(uname.equals(inf.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("employeeLoginResult", "message", message1); 

        }
        else if(uname.equals(inf2.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf2.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf2.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf2.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("adminLoginResult", "message", message2); 
        }

        else
        {
            return new ModelAndView("RedirectTondex", "message","Sorry, username or password error");  
        }
    }
```

Right now I have hardcoded the values for login in a java class which are InfoManager and InfoEmployee. I map the jsp to the other jsp's in the controller.

My Problem is that I want to redirect or include to the index file if nothing matches i.e. in the controller else statement.

If i give the reference of index in here, it only searches the WEB-INF/jsp directory as I have coded in the servlet dispatcher class like here

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

So I thought of two solutions 
1 being that I could make a jsp to show the user some wrong stuff and redirect it to the index from there if it is possible.
2 redirect directly from the controller to the index and pass a message to index with the ModelAndView type method as the code mentioned above.

Any help or suggestion for the problem is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in several ways. One would be to return:

```
return new RedirectView("redirectedUrl");
```

Or you can use

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/abc.htm")
```

Or move the index file in web-inf/jsp  and make it a JSP and redirect like:

```
return new ModelAndView("index")
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use your second suggestion. Would redirecting the file from a separate jsp work?

Comment: I guess it would work. If you create a JSP and add a redirect clause there. But if you secure the jsp with a filter for only logged in users and you haven't logged in (once you create the actual security)  you might not be able to access it without loging in first

Comment: Also wanted to ask whether the redirect in ModelAndView suggestion could take a  message to the index?

Comment: Yes in order to take a message to the index you need to add it in the model. That's why it's Model and View. View is the page you go, model is basically a map of values you pass to that view. It's a bit broad question to answer here but yes that's how you use MVC - you pass values from the controller to the view using the model ;)

Comment: I can't seem to pass the message to be displayed in the index file. The message passed goes to the index file and is added in the URL not inside the file. I did return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.jsp","mess","Wrong Password or Username");

Comment: Is there any solution to tackle this situation??

Comment: There are many solution but that's a big question to be answered here

Comment: Read about spring security, examples etc